# Playing with getter function in a js object, why my code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, object, getter

I wrote the followning code in the chromeconsole and when I hit enter it returns me the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
Why?

```
let obj = {
    p1=1,
    p2=2,
    get koko(){conslole.log("koko");}}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `function koko()` instead? I don't think `get` is valid JS.

Comment: It should be `p1:1, p2:2`, also `console`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in setting the object values.
They should be like this:

```
let obj = {
    p1: 1,
    p2: 2,
    get koko() { console.log('koko') }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should be:

```
let obj = {
    p1:1,
    p2:2,
    get koko(){console.log("koko")}
}
```